# Hide users by id in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I got a page where I display all my authors of the blog. Unfortunately Wordpress also displays the admin. So i disabled him by his role (1 is admin, I guess…) But there are one or two more users who aren't admin which I need to exclude from the list.

```
    <?php
        $roles = array('author');
        $args = array(
        'role'         => $role,
        'exclude'      => array(1, 2),
        'orderby' => $role
    ); ?>
```

This is the code where I exclude the admin from the list. Can I expand it by excluding an user by his id?

Any help would be great!

Cheers
Moe

Answer (score 0):

The `exclude` argument is excluding users by their *user* ID (not *role* ID). From the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users):

> **exclude** - An array of IDs. Users matching these IDs will not be returned, regardless of the other arguments. It will be ignored if the include argument is set.

(...or a *a comma-separated list of authors ids* if you're using `wp_list_authors()`)

Therefore in your case you've actually excluded **user ID**s 1 and 2 (not *roles* 1 and 2). It just happen to be that your administrator probably has one of these IDs.

Therefore all you should do is to add the user IDs you wish to exclude to your *exclude* array.

Comment: yeah you are right with the first one. but the admin has its own exlude, it's called "exclude_admin"… but setting this to true doesn't hide my admin :/

Comment: That's a completely different question/issue. I suggest you see [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/exclude-admin-from-author-list) regarding the `exclude_admin` problem

Comment: exclude_admin just shows up in wp_list_authors. You're right. I solved my problem now with include instead of exclude…